# Перобразование последовательности в sql

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой столбец, нужно получить такой из него 1,2,3,4,5,6,6

То есть наименьшее число - это всегда 1. Это древовидная структура

Comment: в mysql вот такое должно работать `UPDATE thetable cross join (select min(IDLEVEL) m from thetable) t2 SET IDLEVEL= IDLEVEL+(1-t2.m)` В SQL не знаю

Comment: Указывайте точную DBMS, включая версию. "Общего" решения не существует.

Comment: `update tab set idlevel=idlevel+3`